# Sony Z1 Compact: will encrypting my phone disable the camera button?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera, encryption, sony-xperia-z1

I just bought a Sony Z1 Compact with Android 4.4. It has a special camera button on the side. When the phone is off, you can press this button for a longer time, and the camera apps opens directly, even when you have a PIN lock. The lock is not disabled, only for this app. So after making a picture, when you try to open the image, you first have to enter the PIN.

I would like to encrypt the phone, but I'm afraid that this will disable this function. Does anybody knows how this works?

---

**Update: I encrypted the phone plus external SD card, and the camera button still works.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you wont lose the functionality of lock screen camera. But check once before encrypting because you need to hard reset/repair to decrypt xperia phones.

Answer (score -2):

What about, if you transfer your data to a computer, then you try to encrypt your phone and if it works, you can transfer data from computer to phone. If it doesn't works, you can still hard reset it.